# MongoDB shut down in the middle of the night, can't get back up

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, nginx

I pushed some changes to the server tonight, which tested great on my local machine.  When I went to test on the live server, it wasn't letting me connect, so I noticed mongodb stopped running.  Exit code was 14.  Now it's exit code 48.  Here is my repair log:

```
2019-06-21T02:30:28.216-0400 W ASIO     [initandlisten] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2019-06-21T02:30:28.217-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] finished checking dbs
2019-06-21T02:30:28.217-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2019-06-21T02:30:28.217-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Shutting down session sweeper thread
2019-06-21T02:30:28.218-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Finished shutting down session sweeper thread
2019-06-21T02:30:28.257-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2019-06-21T02:30:28.257-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-06-21T02:30:28.257-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:0
root@pottstownrumble:~# mongod
2019-06-21T02:30:35.258-0400 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-06-21T02:30:35.262-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=13525 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=pottstownrumble
2019-06-21T02:30:35.262-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.10
2019-06-21T02:30:35.262-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: c389e7f69f637f7a1ac3cc9fae843b635f20b766
2019-06-21T02:30:35.262-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2019-06-21T02:30:35.262-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-06-21T02:30:35.262-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-06-21T02:30:35.262-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-06-21T02:30:35.262-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2019-06-21T02:30:35.262-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-06-21T02:30:35.262-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-06-21T02:30:35.262-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-06-21T02:30:35.262-0400 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use
2019-06-21T02:30:35.262-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-06-21T02:30:35.262-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
```

Please, someone help me understand why it says something else is listening there . I'm exhausted and our big event is in 5 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use netstat to see whats using the port:

```
netstat -pnltu | grep -i "80"
```

https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/check-service-running-linux-port/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like something is occupying port 27017. You need to find that process and kill it.

To find it use

`sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 27017 | grep LISTEN`

The second column contains PID of this process.
You could also use `ps` to see more details about it.

Then use `sudo kill <process-id>`  to kill it.

e.g.

```
mjaniec@amjay:~$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 27017 | grep LISTEN
mongod    14903         mongodb   11u  IPv4 25111697      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:27017 (LISTEN)
mjaniec@amjay:~$ sudo kill -9 14903
mjaniec@amjay:~$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 27017 | grep LISTEN
mjaniec@amjay:~$
```